# Partial Refresh for combo box choices

Tags: combobox, refresh, partial

[Click here to view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bcgsy.png)

I am trying to have two components. One is a combo box called readerGroups1.
The choices for readerGroups1 are populated from an @db Column.

I have the event on change set to partial refresh.

When I select the Reader group, my category combo box is being refreshed and the values are populated properly.

However, when I deselect the reader group that I just selected, the category combo box is not refreshed and the selections are still available.

Not sure what I am doing incorrectly.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: I was able to get it to work. I needed to make sure it wasn't performing validation on the refresh. Since the validation failed on the reader group, the rest of the code does not run and therefore the fields were not reset.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it working by making sure the validation did not process on the refresh. Readergroups is a required field. once it was empty, the validation fired, which then stopped all the other code from running.

Howard from TLCC, David Leedy and Chris Toohey helped me.
thank you